# SonarQube Vulnerability - S3749 - Issue with @Config

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

Given is the scenario for `@ConfigurationProperties`, where internal and external are defined as -

```
consumers:
   internal = some value
   external = other value
```

And mapped to following class -

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "consumers")
public class ConsumerConfig {

private String internal;

private String external;
... getter and settter.
}
```

for field `internal` and `external`, SonarQube scan is giving error for rule `S3749` -

> `Annotate this member with "@Autowired", "@Resource", "@Inject", or "@Value", or remove it`

How to resolve this. This scenario looks valid for the @Controller @Service and Other class annotation but how this will be applicable in this case.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.8.RELEASE

Comment: it was mistake, one should not use `@Component` for `@ConfigurationProperties`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Component` from there it's not belong there only `@ConfigurationProperties` will do.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have already mentioned in the comments.